# Scale/Architecture challenge

Tags: architecture

I recently had an interview with a well known and highly successful company and everything went swimmingly except the architecture section - I got stuck, and come up with half an answer, but it was clear I didn't have enough experience in that area. Fair enough but I think when it comes to scale this big, you don't get experience without experiencing it, and you don't get that unless you can get a job in one of those companies.. anyway! I've been mulling it over since and have yet to come up with what I consider a great solution.

It goes something roughly like this:

> We want to do something nice for our customers. We want a website set
>   up where users can enter their email address, and we'll give them a
>   voucher for one free X (Burger, taxi ride, month of streaming,
>   whatever company may offer). We will give away 10 million of these
>   vouchers. We expect that due to the high demand, we'll run out within
>   5 minutes. We must under no circumstances give a single user(email address) more than one voucher or give out more than the allocated number of vouchers number of vouchers, but it
>   wouldn't be the end of the world to give
>   out slightly less.

Design a system architecture that could handle this scale of traffic

I'd really love to hear some opinions and ideas :)

Answer (score 0):

I would try to clarify additional non-functional requirements, like what does it mean slightly less? Because 5 entries less or 5k entries less is a big difference.
And whether there are any specific requirements to respond time? And whether there are any requirements for the voucher codes.

The first solution which comes to my mind is just using Lambda function with some kind of hash function from email as a voucher code. That way we ensure that the same email will always receive the same voucher code, so no need to check against storage.

Then you can configure that your lambda will not scale more than (threshold) in parallel and before giving a token you can check the count of already registered emails that it is less or equals 10M-threshold. Where threshold is amount of concurrent functions.

Comment: Slightly less would be, say... 100? A question I should have asked maybe! I feel like they made it relatively clear without going in to an exact number.. When I say architecture, I mean load balancers, redis instances, app servers, etc. Not using a cloud provider and paying a lot for a "brute force solution"